# Linux pipes communication

Tags: c, linux, file, process, pipe

I have the following program

```
#include<stdio.h>
FILE *f;   
int main()
{
int pfd[2];
int pfd1[2];
int pfd2[2];
int pid1;
int pid2;

pipe(pfd);
pipe(pfd1);
if(pfd<0||pfd1<0)
{
  printf("Eroare la crearea pipe-ului\n");
  exit(1);
}

f=fopen("date","r");
pid1=fork();

if(pid1==0){

    close(pfd[1]);
    close(pfd1[0]);
    char c;
    int rd;
    while((rd=read(pfd[0],&c,1))>0){

         printf("%c",c);
         if(c>='A'&&c<='Z') {printf(" mare ");printf("%d:",write(pfd[1],&c,1));}

    }
    close(pfd1[1]);
    close(pfd[0]);
    exit(0);
}

pid2=fork();

 if(pid2==0){

    close(pfd1[1]);
    close(pfd[0]);
    close(pfd[1]);
    char c;
    int rd=read(pfd1[0],&c,1);
    while((rd=read(pfd1[0],&c,1))>0){

        printf("-2-%c",c);

    }
    close(pfd1[0]);

    exit(0);

}
 if(pid1>0&&pid2>0){
    close(pfd[0]);
    close(pfd1[1]);
    close(pfd1[0]);
    while(!feof(f)){
        char c;
        fscanf(f,"%c",&c);
        if(feof(f)) break;
        write(pfd[1],&c,1);
    }
    close(pfd[1]);

}
```

}
What it does is it reads from a file and then sends the characters to the first children and that children extracts uppercase letters and sends them to the second children. Everything works fine if i send all characters but when i want to send only uppercase write functions return -1. My question is why this is happening?

Comment: If `write()` fails, it will set `errno` to a value that can be decoded with `strerror()` to tell you what went wrong.

Comment: it return -1 in write

Comment: `errno` is not the same as the return value. It's more like a global variable, that many C library routines use to indicate why an operation failed. A return of -1 tells you "it failed", the  `errno` (and the string it decodes to in `strerror()` ) tells you *why*.

Comment: Looks like the file was closed - `close(pfd[1]);`, then you try to write to it - `write(pfd[1],&c,1));`

Comment: it was the descriptor of the pipe wrong.problem solved